# Open a site, log in and get data with App

Tags: ionic2

I'm making an app and I need to know if this I'm trying to do is possible. I need to open a link from a website, which will open a login screen, and then get the data from the site that opens, with HTTP.get.

[First Page](http://graber.zatix.com.br/portal/Login.html#main)

[image: First Page Screenshot]

I have the login and the password, but I need a function that automatically fills the fields and enter, to enter the next page, without showing to the user of preference.

The next page I can get the data with HTTP.get

Comment: you want to open an app with a url? or you.want to fetch data to app from website? or are you want to cache uaername password? it seems kinda vague

Comment: I want to fetch data to app from website, but I have to be logged in to get the data of the page that I want.